# detect css transitions while javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr, css-transitions

I have been using modernizr with javascript to decide whether css transitions is available, but is there a way to check if css transitions are working, without using javascript?

Comment: If some CSS properties are not supported you can still declare them, they will just get ignored.

Comment: Generally, no. But what specifically do you want to happen if transitions are working / not working?

Comment: So you want to prevent JS execution depending on CSS support?

Comment: No, I just want to detect if css transitions are working without using JS.

Comment: Still not getting it. "if transitions are not working javascript should take over with the animations" / "without using JS" - Does that make any sense?

Comment: "No, I just want to detect if css transitions are working without using JS" - No, it's not possible without javascript. It's the reason modernizr is used in the first place. IMO if a user has javascript disabled and the consequence is that they don't see a fancy transition, it's not a big deal if it's still usable. Don't worry about it, move on.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense until you say what action you want to take based on whether CSS transitions are supported or not when javascript is disabled.  We need to know what you're really trying to do!  Most people want to detect css transitions and use a javascript-based solution if transtions are not supported.  Since you are asking about no-javascript, we have no idea what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only scenario where that would make sense is a browser without CSS animation support and with JS disabled. There you could display some message like "Please upgrade your browser or enable JS."
You could try server-side UserAgent sniffing there, but I wouldn't recommend it. First of all, it's not reliable and second it's simply not worth the effort. Anyone using such a browser is used to limited functionality.